# Why do I have 80v from my black wire to the ground and 30v from the neutral wire to ground on my single pole switch^

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I just bought a house and looking to fix things up. I encountered a single pole light switch in a metallic box with three NM white cables coming in (2 wires and a ground).

With the switch on the "OFF" position, when I test the "power in black wire" (on the bottom screw terminal) with the neutrals, my multimeter reads a normal 120V. From the same "power in black wire" to the ground, my multimeter reads around 80V (77-79V). Finally, from the neutral wires to the ground, it reads 30V. Having said that, when I test the ground and the neutral wires with my NCVT-1 Voltage tester, it doesn't detect voltage.

Now, I would like to fix this, but I'm not sure where to start. My hypotheses is a "bad ground", but I'm not sure what to do from there...

I checked the ground wires in the switch's metallic box and everything seemed
perfectly wired, with a pigtail.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Adam

EDIT : Please see update in the comments.

[image: Switch]

[image: Inside Switch]

Comment: Are there any outlets or switches between this switch location and the breaker box?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. It's hard to say for sure, but from what I can see through the holes I made in the walls/ceiling, it seems like the problem is between the NM cable feeding the switch mentioned in my original post (which gives me the weird readings mentioned in my original post) and another switch, closer to the breaker box, on which all the wires give a correct reading (120V between black and ground, 120V between black and neutral and 0V between neutral and ground). Just to be sure, I also checked the voltage at the breaker box, and everything is A1.